# How to import Docdoku plm on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, enterprise

I have downloaded Docdoku plm from github, and imported on to eclipse workspace. I have configured glassfish 3.1 application server. But I am getting many errors to this Maven based Enterprise application. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting? How's your Maven pom looks like? We need more information